# can't set color using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've started learning jQuery and I was [trying](http://jsfiddle.net/kunalkrishna85/LbhyhnyL/) to set the `color` of a `tr` but unable to do so. However, I'm able to successfully update other css attribute e.g. `font-style`. From what I've learnt so far to set the CSS property and value we use:

```
$(selector).css(property,value)
```

So, please point out the error.

HTML:

```
<table class="csr">
<tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="aTable">
<tr><td>Row 11</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 22</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 33</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

table.aTable td{
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

jQuery:

```
$( "tr:first" ).css( "font-style", "italic" );
$( "tr:first" ).css( "color", "red" );
$( "tr:first" ).css( "background-color","yellow" );

$( ".aTable tr:first" ).css( "font-style", "italic" );
$( ".aTable tr:first" ).css( "background-color","yellow" );
```

Comment: Your code looks valid, could you try official example? Maybe try step-by-step modifications and watch for differences :) http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: You change `tr` color to `red`, but `td` still has `blue` color set.

Comment: @Justinas thnx changing to `$( "td:first" ).css( "color", "red" )` did the job

Comment: [Your code works perfectly fine](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/endrL9w0/). Are you including a link to jQuery?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py yes jQuery 2.1.0. moreover I want my first row of first table to be red

Comment: @chipChocolate.py It actually doesn't work completely because of CSS priorities.The first row should have red text in both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying the css attributes to the TR which is later overwritten by the TD which is a subelement so appears on top of the TR.

Also you can combine your css like so:

```
$('tr:first td').css({
           'font-style':'italic',
           'color':'red',
           'background-color':'yellow'}
);

$('.aTable tr:first td').css({
           'font-style':'italic',
           'background-color':'yellow'}
);
```

And technically the first selector also catches the second table's first row.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of CSS priority, the color is applying to `tr`, which means that the `td { color:blue }` is heavier and thus applies. Applying the style to the `td` inside the `tr` is one possible solution :

```
$( "tr:first td" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7c5sa36/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set as below:

```
$( "tr:first>td" ).css( "color", "red" );
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hj3gqmxw/)